# How to analyze datasets collected by different companies

Tags: dataset

I have data from six different experimental groups that were collected by two different companies (three groups were collected by company A e the other three by company B).

I'm interested in compare a variable X present in all of the groups.

But I need to check if eventual differences in sex, age, race and income(six categorical values) variables in the samples collected by each company affected X.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the variable X an attribute of individuals or of the companies? Is it numerical or categorical?

Comment: Is a binary categorical variable and an attribute from the individuals…

Comment: You say: "I'm interested in compare a variable X present in all of the groups." What means "compare"? Do you want to compare group means? Or group distributions? Or are you rather interested in how X depends on your features? Or both? Please update the question itself, don't just put the information into comments. In general, it would help if you could always give an excerpt of the data table or at least the data types, a clear description of your goal, and maybe shortly point out the motivation.